# Error executing the result of cx_freeze using pycrypto

Tags: cx-freeze, pycrypto

I am trying to freeze a Little python program using pycrypto library in Windows. Last version of everything including cx_freeze.

After running >python setup.py build apparently everything goes nice.

But running the exe file generated reports the following error : ImportError: cannot import name _AES

The error is reported by AES.py file which is part of pycrypto lybrary.

I have copied the pycrypto structure in the same directory where setup.py is and I played with the contents of setup.py making a lot of subtle changes but I always get the same error.

Does someone know what I am missing?

Comment: Install the pre-compiled PyCrypto modules from [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto)

Comment: pre-compiled PyCrypto helped me, I had the same problem as original poster. THank you.