# cx_freeze and pycrypto is missing modules?

Tags: python, distutils

Here is my setup.py file for Python 3.3:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": [
        "os","io","copy","struct","hashlib","random",
        "urllib","pycurl","json","Crypto"
    ],
    "includes": [        "urllib.parse",    ],
    "excludes": ["tkinter"],
    "icon":"backup.ico"
}

setup(  name = "BlindBackup",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "BlindBackup client",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("backup.py", base=None)])
```

I can execute "py -3 setup.py build_exe" but the exe won't work. By starting the generated backup.exe I get this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto.Cipher'; Crypto is not a package
```

However, Crypto is a package! I have also tried to add these into the includes section:

```
    "includes": ["urllib.parse",
                 "Crypto","Crypto.Cipher","Crypto.Cipher.AES",],
```

But then I cannot even build the exe:

```
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
   distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
   dist.run_commands()
 File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 929, in run_commands
   self.run_command(cmd)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
   cmd_obj.run()
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 232, in run
   freezer.Freeze()
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 603, in Freeze

   self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 343, in _GetMouleFinder
   finder.IncludeModule(name)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 678, in IncludeModule
   namespace = namespace)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 386, in _ImportModule
   raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto.Cipher'
```

Which makes no sense, because **there is** a module named Crypto.Cipher.

You can test the same setup.py script with python 3 - just create a backup.py script and put this inside:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

It has been suggested that I install precompiled voidspace modules ( see [Error executing the result of cx_freeze using pycrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066437/error-executing-the-result-of-cx-freeze-using-pycrypto) ) but it doesn't work either. I did not want to write comment to a 7 month old question, maybe that is what I should have done? Anyway, I have this problem now and I cannot fix this on my own. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was silly. I have created a module in my project called "crypto.py". It is true that this module was a different one under Linux. However, under Windows, the package "Crypto" and the module "crypto" appeared to be the same. cx_Freeze confused them, and tried to find Cipher module under the crypto.py "packacge" which was a module instead.

Refactored my module to a different name and now it works!